# An elegant one-line solution to extract data from Nested Tuples from divmod

Tags: python, variables, lambda, tuples, divmod

assuming the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
end_time = datetime.now()

delta = end_time - start_time
delta_ms = delta.microseconds
```

what is the most elegant way to simplify the conversion of the timedelta object to mins,secs and millisecs?

The one-liner I have below, requires two calculations of `divmod(delta_ms,1000)`, is there any way, keeping it to one line, that it only needs to be calculated once?

```
mins,secs,ms = divmod(divmod(delta_ms,1000),60) + (divmod(delta_ms,1000)[1],)
```

I also have the following, which is two lines of code but only calculates `divmod(delta_ms,1000)` once:

```
unwrap = lambda x: divmod(x[0],60) + (x[1],)
mins,secs,ms = unwrap(divmod(delta_ms,1000))
```

Comment: [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) is a built in python function that returns a tuple

Comment: what's wrong with assigning the results of `divmod(delta_ms,1000)` to a pair of local variables??

Comment: Where is `unwrap` coming from?

Comment: nothing is wrong with that. It is more the theoretical solution that I am interested in of combining the expression into one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you missed a `[0]` in your second `divmod` :) You might want to change that:

```
mins,secs,ms = divmod(divmod(delta_ms,1000)[0],60) + (divmod(delta_ms,1000)[1],)
```

Answering your question, if you are looking for elegant based on amount of lines it takes up, than your above solution would the most so. However, you are running `divmod` an extra, unnecessary time, which can be solved in one-line (much less elegant, uses `;`):

```
var1, var2 = divmod(delta_ms,1000);mins,secs,ms = divmod(var1,60) + (var2,)
```

Or two lines:

```
var1, var2 = divmod(delta_ms,1000)
mins,secs,ms = divmod(var1,60) + (var2,)
```

Comment: nicer is `var1, var2 = divmod(...)`

Comment: can you explain the `_var = divmod(delta_ms,1000);mins,secs,ms` part especially the use of `_`

Comment: @wim true, unpacking should be the way to go :) thanks!

Comment: @alexmcf the `_` does not alter the variable in any way (apart from the name), it is just part of a convention that I follow :)